# Bound variable in ViewModel is not updating the displayed value

Tags: mvvm, data-binding, maui

I was trying to create an countdown timer in ViewModel but i didnt found any method to do that so i ve tried to do this with task delay and while loop but it ends after first task delay. Do u know any other way how to do that or how to repair that one.

```
public PageViewModel()
{
    MethodName();
}

public async void MethodName()
{
    CountSeconds = 10;
    while (CountSeconds > 0)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        CountSeconds--;
    }
}
```

Comment: So, what does the question have to do with MAUI? Do you believe the shown code would be any different in a console application? As you can see works as expected: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QfEu.png

Comment: its not working in my Viewmodel, when i set first countseconds-- it shows me 9 on screen but when i let it thsi way it shows me 10

Comment: Sorry, but how am I supposed to know what you are doing in your ViewModel that prevents it from working? As I have shown, the code is working as intended. No issue to be found.

Comment: Use Sytem.Timers, not Task.Delay

Comment: The current answers and other suggestions are more or less irrelevant. Your code *would* work fine, except that there is a problem **elsewhere**. Questions like this have been asked COUNTLESS times, both at StackOverflow and elsewhere. [Read the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-bindings-to-mvvm). Google for tutorials or videos. Get some existing example to work. Then when you understand, do it yourself. If stuck, come back here and **add to question** all the other places in c# and xaml involved in getting this binding to work.

Comment: I've edited the title and tags: it is NOT a problem with Task.Delay. It is a problem with data binding between a view and a view model. (This can be easily demonstrated, by removing Task.Delay line.) HINT: The revised title and tags show the terms to **search for**, if need help understanding what is going wrong.

Comment: does your VM implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Dispatacher.StartTimer()` ([available in the DispatcherExtensions class](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/blob/78647901e969de5c948cb9e87eacd055ad4b9604/src/Core/src/Dispatching/DispatcherExtensions.cs#L66)) to create a function that will execute every x seconds/minutes/hours (depending of what you're setting) using the device's clock.

To access the Application's Dispatcher from any class, use the following line:

```cs
var dispatcher = Application.Current.Dispatcher;
```

Since there is no documentation available yet for MAUI, you can read [the Device.StartTimer() documentation from Xamarin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.device.starttimer?view=xamarin-forms), which acts exactly the same.

Comment: Thanks i ve used dispatcher and it is working   ' CountSeconds = 10;
            var Dispatcher = Application.Current.Dispatcher;
            Dispatcher.StartTimer(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1), () =>
            {
               if(CountSeconds > 0)
                {
                    CountSeconds--;
                    return true;
                }
               else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            });'

Comment: Please accept the answer which is useful for you so that it will help others who have similar problems. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you can`t see others is related to context. You trying to run async code in non-async context.
To solve this problem you can do several ways, which way to choose is your choice and depends on your needs:

```
await MethodName();

async Task MethodName()
{
    CountSeconds = 10;
    while (CountSeconds > 0)
    {
       await Task.Delay(1000);
      
       CountSeconds--;
    }
}
```

Another way is to create various of tasks and execute them, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.waitall?view=net-6.0) you can see methods, which can help you.

And as Rand Random metioned it's not about MAUI, it`s about understanding of async programming itself, so for you will be usefull read more about it.